# Can you bulk upload using SnowflakeDbConnection?

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bulk-load

I have this following code, it can insert one record at a time. It take long time to load the data line by line.

```
using (SnowflakeDbConnection connection = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
 connection.ConnectionString = connstr;

 connection.Open(); 

 int rowsAffected;

 using (SnowflakeDbCommand sqlcomm = 
 SnowflakeDbCommand)connection.CreateCommand())
 {

  sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

 sqlcomm.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0}({1},{2}) 
values('9',  'Value99')", DestinationTableName, "ValueID", "FullName");

rowsAffected = sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

I am looking for something like this

```
using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(this.connection))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "DestinationTableName";
    bulk.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system.html

Comment: Thanks, it is not straight from the SQL Sever, you will need to dump in to files and then load.

Comment: It is "the Snowflake way" to import bulk data via cloud storage and not by multiple inserts.  Write to cloud storage + COPY INTO _table_ is assumed to be faster when you have a lot of data.  Many INSERTs may be worse than you think due to how tables are stored "write once".

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using the COPY INTO <"table"> command. There is some setup that you will need to do in order to get this working.

1. You will need to create an internal stage within Snowflake using the PUT command.
2. From here, you will then use the COPY INTO <"table"> command.

Based on this, what I would do is have your bulk data stored within a file (Snowflake supports many different file formats), and then pass that to the COPY INTO command's parameters.

The documentation does a better job of explaining this than I ever could :)

Overview of copying from local FS: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system.html

Syntax for PUT command: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/put.html

Syntax for COPY INTO command: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: This will work but is a little manual.  If you write your data into an Azure blob storage and configure that as an _external_ stage, you can still use COPY INTO _table_.

Comment: The Snowflake .NET Connector does not support the PUT command yet: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dotnet-driver.html

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Snowflake Connector for .NET](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net) and the **Bind Parameter** example in how to insert multiple rows at the same time (but still a small number).

You should look into writing your compressed data to an Azure blob "Snowflake staging area" and import via the `COPY INTO table` command
[I'm assuming you use Snowflake on Azure - works for AWS S3 and GCP as well].